# GORM embedded struct not working correctly

Tags: go, go-gorm

I receive this error

```
controllers/users.go:61:36: user.ID undefined (type models.User has no field or method ID)
```

when using

```
var user models.User

...

jwtToken, err := generateJWT(user.ID, user.Username)
```

The definition of `User` model:

```
package models

import "time"

type BaseModel struct {
    ID        uint `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    CreatedAt time.Time
    UpdatedAt time.Time
}

type User struct {
    BaseModel BaseModel `gorm:"embedded"`
    Username  string    `json:"username"`
    Password  string    `json:"password"`
}
```

Actually I put `BaseModel` in different file but in the same package with `User`.    Migration works fine as table `users` have all columns in `BaseModel`. What is the problem? I use `golang` 1.18 and latest version of `GORM`

Comment: what is your table structure? do you have columns `id, username, password, created_at, updated_at`?

Comment: Didd you try using `gorm.Model` in the `BaseModel` instead of defining your own attributes?

Comment: can you try doing this `generateJWT(user.BaseModel.ID, user.Username)`

Comment: @NeenadIngole it works but what is wrong with the way I define it. The reason I defined it is because I don't want deleted_at column

Comment: @NeenadIngole it seems to work, let me test more. You can write an answer so that I can mark it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used `BaseModel` as attribute in your model so even though gorm can very well map it to the table column to access it, you have to use the attribute name

To access you would do

```
jwtToken, err := generateJWT(user.BaseModel.ID, user.Username)
```

you could also try this next code to see if it works otherwise the above will work for sure

```
type BaseModel struct {
    ID        uint `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    CreatedAt time.Time
    UpdatedAt time.Time
}

type User struct {
    BaseModel `gorm:"embedded"`
    Username  string    `json:"username"`
    Password  string    `json:"password"`
}
```

now you might be able to access it like your original pattern

```
jwtToken, err := generateJWT(user.ID, user.Username)
```